# CSS3 columns, reduce number if small width

Tags: css, responsive-design, width, multiple-columns

Is it possible to use the CSS3 columns with a minimum column width; such that if the container is resized to be smaller than the current number of columns, that the number of columns is decreased?

For example this HTML http://jsfiddle.net/3LStR/. There are 3 columns. I want that to turn to two columns if the width of the `.cols3` div is below 400px;

I found this reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-width.asp but that was no help.

I want three columns if the total width allows this,

```
<---------------------------------->

<-------><-------><------->
```

But if the total width is smaller, I want less columns:

```
<----------------------->

<-------><------->
```

And

```
<--------------->

<------->
```

And if the total width is much larger, I still want only three columns:

```
<------------------------------------------------------------>

<-------><-------><------->
```

Comment: Are we talking about a dynamically re-sizable container on your web page or the size of the viewport (screen)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you can just base the columns of the window width and not specifically the container, this is where Media Queries come in handy.

Give your container `width:100%` and then set a `max-width` where you want it to stop stretching, in this case `600px`.

```
.cols3 {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 600px;
}
```

Wrap your column setup in a media query for the minimum width (`400px`) you want the columns to start displaying:

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .cols3 {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #000;

    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #000;

    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
    column-rule: 1px solid #000;
  }
}
```

Finally, set up your last breakpoint for the maximum number of columns you want at the right size you want (`600px`):

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .cols3 {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/A6vjv/show/

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/A6vjv/

Again, this is based on the window width, not the actual container width. You may need to adjust depending on your container's styles and placement in the document. Otherwise, you'll need some fancy javascript to do breakpoints based on the container alone.